# Little help with logitech g910

Tags: keyboard, backlight, logitech, github

New Linux Ubuntu user here.
After looking after some drivers for this keyboard, I found this on github.

https://github.com/MatMoul/g810-led

I have managed to install this, and the rainbow effect stopped on my g910 keyboard.
But how do I actually change the color on the keyboard?
I understand that I have to get into the terminal, and change it from there, but don't know how to.

When i type

```
g910-led --help
```

Then I get this:

---

g910-led
Version : 0.2.7

Usage: g910-led [OPTIONS...] [command] (command arguments)

Commands:

-a {color}  Set all keys color

-g {keygroup} {color}   Set key group color

-k {key} {color}    Set key color

-mr {value} Set MR key (0-1)

-mn {value} Set MN key (0-7) (M1=1, M2=2, M3=4) (M1+M2=3, M1+M3=5, ...)

-gkm {value}    Set GKeys mode (0=Mapped to FKeys, 1=Independent)

-an {color} Set all keys color without commit

-gn {keygroup} {color}  Set key group color without commit

-kn {key} {color}   Set key color without commit

-c  Commit change

-fx ... Use --help-effects for more detail

< {profile} Set a profile from a file (use --help-samples for more detail)
|   Set a profile from stdin (for scripting) (use --help-samples for more detail)

--startup-mode {startup mode}   Set startup mode

--list-keyboards List connected keyboards

--print-device  Print device information for the keyboard

--help  This help

--help-keys Help for keys in groups

--help-effects  Help for native effects

--help-samples  Usage samples

Options:

-dv Device vendor ID, such as 046d for Logitech. Can be omitted to match any vendor ID

-dp Device product ID, such as c337 for Logitech G810. Can be omitted to match any product ID

-ds Device serial number, Can be omitted to match the first device found
-tuk    Test unsuported keyboard with one of supported protocol (1-3) -dv and -dp are required

Values:

color formats : RRGGBB (hex value for red, green and blue)

speed formats : SS (hex value for speed 01 to ff)

key values :    abc... 123... and other (use --help-keys for more detail)

group values :  logo, indicators, fkeys, ... (use --help-keys for more detail)

startup mode :  wave, color

---

I fail at writing the right line to change the lights.
I hope someone can write an example of how to change all the keys blue.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i found out of this.
At first I tried to run:

```
g910-led -a 0000ff
```

Where 0000ff is the color in hex format.

And got a response that said: Matching or compatible device not found !

After a while I got some help from the creator himself at [githubhttps://github.com/MatMoul/g810-led/issues/140](https://github.com/MatMoul/g810-led/issues/140)

He said that all I have to do was to run the command as sudo liek this:

```
sudo g910-led -a 0000ff
```

Then I goot all my keys blue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to save others time. I managed to get this working on the g512, but it took a bit of digging:

`sudo ./g810-led -dv <vendor_id> -dp <product_id> -tuk 1 -a ff0000`

The above would turn all your keys red on a G512. To get the values of vendor_id and and product_id you can do:

`sudo ./g810-led --list-keyboards`

I'm using `./` because I compiled my version as instructed in the INSTALL.md, and I'm too lazy to add the extra bin folder to $PATH